# Attempt to insert record on page where this table is not allowed

Tags: typo3, typo3-tca

I get the message above (Attempt to insert record on page where this table is not allowed) when trying to create a new record from an extension.

- The "page" i try to create the record in is a sysfolder and not a page
- `t3lib_extMgm::allowTableOnStandardPages('user_myext_categories');` is set
- there are already records of `categories` on this page
- there is no `'type' =>` definition in TCA, but the table itself is registered in TCA like the other tables from this extension (and they work)

Any hints on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the creation of tables of this type is deactivated via Page-TS-Config? Via `mod.web_list.allowedNewTables / deniedNewTables` it is possible to disable the creation of new tables.

You need to check each Page-TS-Config in the rootline or have a look at the info module.

Perhaps try to create a new "root" page and add your table there. If that works, it is a Page-TS-Config configuration:)

Comment: wow, never thought to meet so much irc.freenode.net#typo3 people here ;) thanks, will try this.

Comment: Nope, no `allowedNewTables` or `deniedNewTables`, scanned the whole tree

Comment: you are root? Tried to create table somewhere else? What happens if you edit some of the existing tables? (perhaps we can chat in #typo3, but i am afk for some minutes)

Comment: the rootiest, yes. Editing existing records is working. I don't even see the record I want to create in the list when clicking "create new record". There are already records, so I just can press the "new record" icon in the lists table header. (unfortunately no, currently behind a blocking proxy)

Comment: Check TCA of your table. In section `ctrl` which value has `rootLevel` perhaps remove it or set it to 0.

Answer (score 3):

in the ext_table you need this: `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('XXXXXX');`