# Attempt to insert record on page ... where this table, fe_users/fe_groups, is not allowed

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I looked at this [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787714/attempt-to-insert-record-on-page-where-this-table-is-not-allowed) on here but I didn't understand half of what everyone is saying there as I'm not very familiar with TypoScript...

Let  me start from my point of view: I got a backend tree in TYPO3 6.2 that looks like this:
`Data` is of type "Folder" where I want to store my records.
`Userroles`, `Admins` and `Lawyer` are of Type "Standard" while the last two contain the Plugin "Website Users".
[image: Backend-Tree]
[image: Behaviour Website Users]

Now I want to add a new fe_usergroup to page `Userroles`:

[image]
[image]
I get following error:
[image: 1: Attempt to insert record on page 'Userroles' (39) where this table, fe_groups, is not allowed]
It's the same when I try inserting a new fe_user in `Admins`:
[image: 1: Attempt to insert record on page 'Admins' (40) where this table, fe_users, is not allowed]
So in the other answers from mentioned question they're talking about *Page-TS-Config* - I looked at my Userroles Page and saw this:
[image: TS Page Config] and I went to the Template Analyzer and searched for `allowedNewTables` and `deniedNewTables` but no results. And to the comment: *section ctrl which value has rootLevel* - but those TCAs are from Extbase right? So why would they be wrong...
I must have done something wrong but I have no idea what it could be.
It worked before I think...although I don't know about the usergroups, didn't try to add a new one recently.

Comment: Is the page that you are trying to add usergroups to of type "page" or "directory" (see "General"-tab). Probably it must be of kind "directory" or "folder"

Comment: Post this as an answer, so I can accept it - 'cause I realized that the best and easiest solution in my particular case was simply changing the page-type from "Standard" to "Folder"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the page that you are trying to add usergroups to of type "page" or "directory" (see "General"-tab). Probably it must be of kind "directory" or "folder"

Answer (score 6):

I placed

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('tx_myext_download');
```

into the `ext_tables.php` of `myext` to allow this kind of records.

Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Add in Your ext_tables.php in Your Extension following code:

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('tx_your_extension_table_name');

Comment: If using IRRE records, you need to insert records on regular pages. Therefore, this might be helpful in different cases.

Answer (score 1):

In TYPO3, you have to define, which tables are allowed on standard pages. There is a method in the ExtensionManagementUtility, that does extacly that:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('tx_yourtable');
```

If you have a look at the source, you'll see, that this method ist just one line of code that concatenates table names into the global configuration array, specifically at

```
$GLOBALS['PAGES_TYPES']['default']['allowedTables']
```

Its possible that something in your TYPO3 installation messes with this line. 
Check the value of this configuration value in either the Install Tool or the Confuguration tab in the backend. If this line contains anything other than comma seperated table names, something is wrong. TYPO3 base table names like pages,tt_content,fe_users,fe_groups and so on should also be listed there by default.

Comment: I am not able to check the value of that config value because I can't find it. I opened every tab in "All configuration" in the install tool and searched for "allowedTables" and similar combinations but there were no entries. And in my regular back-end "Configuration" tab there's no $GLOBALS['PAGES_TYPES'] to choose...just lots of others like $GLOBALS['TCA'], ...