# TYPO3 Add new tab to page properties

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I've wasted a full day trying to achieve this :
what i want to do is to add a new tab (lets call it extralinks) to the page properties.
and this tab will contain IRRE item to add links to every page
so i created a new table :

## ext_tables

```
CREATE TABLE links(
    uid int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    link varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (uid)
);
```

and then i added a new file to TCA/Overrides/links.php

## links.php

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}

$GLOBALS['TCA']['links'] = array(
    'ctrl' => array(
        'label' => 'links',
        'title' => 'extralinks',
    ),
    'interface' => '',
    'columns' => array(
        'link' => array(
            'label' => 'extralinks',
            'exclude' => true,
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 50,
                'max' => 255,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            )
        )
    ),
    'types' => [
        '0' => [
            'showitem' => '
                --div--;;LLL:extralinks,
                link
            '
        ]
    ],
    'palettes' => 'extralinks'
);

$linksColumns = array(
    'extralinks' => array(
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'extralinks',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'inline',
            'foreign_table' => 'links',
            'maxitems' => 30,
            'appearance' => [
                'collapseAll' => 1,
                'expandSingle' => 1,
            ],
        )
    )
);
```

now in the same file at the end i need to add this to have tables so i make the following:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('pages', '--div--;Extra links,extralinks;;;;1-1-1', '');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('pages', $linksColumns);
```

when i make this the new tab is there with the new item but when i try to add a link i will get an error which says extralinks doesnt is not a column in pages table -which is understandable-

so when i try this

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('links', '--div--;Extra links,extralinks;;;;1-1-1', '');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('links', $linksColumns);
```

now i dont even see the tab neither the item....
how can i achieve this ?

p.s

- forget the naming its different and i am pretty sure thats not the issue
- i am using typo3-cms 9.5

Comment: If you want to extend table `pages` you have to do this in ext_tables.sql. Then you can extend TCA with Configuration/TCA/Overrides/pages.php. Or you do it as a new model `links`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @Heinz Schilling says, you have to put the fields definition into `TCA/Overrides/pages.php`.

You must also put an "counter"-field to your pages table, so that TYPO3 knows you have irre elements inside this page.

In your `ext_tables.sql` you have to put following:

```
CREATE TABLE pages (
    extralinks int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: after u dud all of what you both said i ended up with the following: : Attempt to insert record on page 'Home' (4) where this table, tx_extralinks, is not allowed

googled it and used the allowedStandardPages still not working :/

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787714/attempt-to-insert-record-on-page-where-this-table-is-not-allowed ? This would be a new question, as this question is solved.

Comment: there is 3 questions solved on stof, regarding this issue, sadly none of them fixed it for me

Comment: i tried something, tried to use input instead of inline for the type of extralinks and then it would save only as int (the counter you mentioned) it wont save string, and as inline it will give me not allowed

Comment: first of all, you have to determine why the link elements can not be saved on regular pages. If you have solve this you are done.

Sadly the only think I know is the `allowTableOnStandardPages` function, so I can't help you about this problem.

Comment: Did you set `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('tx_extralinks');`in your ext_tables.php?